# What are good techniques for determining direct maps of proteins?

Tags: protein-structure, xray-crystallography

I am looking for which techniques to explore to determine electron density maps (or Fourier maps) for a protein (possibly using an assumed model).

In particular, I want to avoid techniques that create difference maps like Fo - Fc, and I think this means I also want to avoid 2Fo - Fc or other types of "sigma_A" maps, which all (I think?) contain data indicating the difference/discrepancy between observed and modeled densities. I believe what I am referring to is a "direct map."

While I'm open to techniques that are **informed** by a candidate model, I don't want F_calc to show up in the actual output. Also, I'd like to reduce model bias as much as possible while still arriving at a direct map (assuming that is the correct nomenclature).

I've seen references to "Iterative OMIT" and various other "OMIT" maps, but could not determine whether those gave the output I'm looking for.

Ideally, I'd like to use techniques that are implemented in open-source libraries, though that may not be an absolute requirement.

Comment: The 2mFo-DFc map is considered to be least biased by the model. Reportedly, it was shown to be least biased [in a paper from 1986](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108767386099622).

Comment: Unrelatedly, I am not certain about it but should this be migrated to SO bioinformatics?

Comment: @marcin, I believe the 2mFo-DFc is still a difference map. Its values (if I understand it correctly) are not intended to be an image of the actual electron density.

Comment: @DavidR they are. 2-1 map looks like direct map, but is less biased. You can google to find various presentations (from lectures and MX workshops) that cover map types. Books such as *Biomolecular Crystallography* probably also cover it.